# Eclipse builds very slow

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, extjs, jersey

Hi i am using jar of hibernate,jersey and Extended js framework in my dynamic web project.

Every time I build it , it takes a lot of time.

Always hangs on 23%, and take time to complete.

Please help me to speed it up.

here is the configuration file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1G
```

Answer (score 0):

Speed of the build depends mostly on the parameters of your computer, as the CPU is working hard to get the job done. If you want faster build, you would need to get better hardware.
I would recommend not to use eclipse as it has no support anymore and swithing to android studio

Comment: System have i3 processor with 6 GB RAM.